# Menu and header: inside or after?

Tags: html

Considering SEO (or maybe not only SEO), which is better - to place main menu inside of header or after it?

F.e.,

```
<div class="container">
  <!-- here goes header -->
</div>
<div class="container">
  <!-- here goes menu -->
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="header">
        <!-- here goes some code bla-bla-bla -->
        <div id="top-menu">
            <!-- here goes menu -->
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the menu should go inside the **nav** tag `<nav> links here </nav>`

Comment: This just your gut feeling or do you have some reasoning behind this?

Comment: I presime you mean that nav is outside of header? Or it is no importance for SEO?